# php--guestbook pager

Tags: php, mysql

i am a new learner of php, now i want to write a simple guestbook. but i don't know how to write the pager's part. any one can instruct me? or give me some example and some tutorials. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nettuts usually has pretty good tutorials => http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

- http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx